# MySQL multiple insert with foreign key from another query

Tags: mysql

I have a simple db structure:

```
node
    id
    name      

measure       
    id        
    node_id 
    time
    value
```

From a microcontroller I get a list of several `time`, `value` readings and a single `node.name`.

Currently I query the db to get `node.id` from `node.name`

```
SELECT id FROM node WHERE name = ?
```

Then I do the multiple inserts

```
INSERT INTO measure (node_id, time, value) VALUES (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), ...
```

Can it be done in a single shot?

Comment: I think we need more information. Where you get the data for the inserts? You could do a join so the data include the node.id. Otherwise you dont have any other way.

Comment: You can use the first query as subquery. But I would keep it as it is.

Comment: @Juan: data comes from a REST api POST request, from there I have to store data in the db.

Comment: as @PaulSpiegel said you could use a subquery. But the cost to get the node_id is probably to low I wouldnt change it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with inline table so you can join

```
INSERT INTO measure (node_id, time, value)
SELECT id, time, value
FROM ( select ? AS time, ? AS value
       union all 
       select ?, ?
       ...
      ) AS inlinedata

CROSS JOIN ( SELECT id FROM node WHERE name = ? )
```

Comment: Ok I got it  -- the second time I read it :) -- I will try it tomorrow, thanks